# Integral involving derivative of delta function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

How to solve integrations of following types:

1. $$
   I_1 = \int d\mathbf{r} [ \mathbf{\nabla_r}f(\mathbf{r})]\cdot [ \mathbf{\nabla_{r'}}g(\mathbf{r'})]\{\mathbf{\nabla_r} \mathbf{\nabla_{r'}}[\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'})]\}
   $$
2. $$
   I_2 = \int d\mathbf{r} [ \mathbf{\nabla_r}f(\mathbf{r})]\cdot [ \mathbf{\nabla_{r'}}g(\mathbf{r'})]\{\mathbf{\nabla_r }[\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'})\cdot \mathbf{A(r)}]\}
   $$

here $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r'}$ are two different vectors in 3D space, $f(\mathbf{r})$ and $g(\mathbf{r'})$ two scalar functions, and $\mathbf{A(r)}$ is a vector field.

I know that for an integral with one derivative of delta function, one can use distributional derivatives as $\int dx f(x) \delta^{(n)}(x-x_0)=(-1)^nf^{(n)}|_{x=x_0}$. But I am confused how to translate this rule for two derivatives of delta functions at different points and a derivative of delta function which dot product of some other vector field.

Comment: $\nabla_{\mathbf {r'}}$ denotes directional derivative?